# How to create a mui transition on hover using pseudo classes?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code for a useStyles hook it is basically a full page background that I want to be changed on hover for some reason it is not working what is the issue , I found a similar solution but it is for css and it is working like charm.

Code that's not working:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    backgroundUser: {
      minHeight: '100vh',
      marginTop: 0,
      marginBottom: -50,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      background: 'linear-gradient(360deg, #fe6b8b 30%, #7DF9FF 70%)',
      '&::after': {
        minHeight: '100vh',
        marginTop: 0,
        marginBottom: -50,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        background: 'linear-gradient(360deg, #dfe566 30%, #7DF334 70%)',
        transition: 'all 3s ease',
      },
      '&:hover:after': {
        opacity: 1,
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Working example:

```css
.FeatureRow {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 260px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, white, gray);
}

.FeatureRow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, red, magenta);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}

.FeatureRow:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="FeatureRow"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `&::after` is missing a `content` property here, and it also need a `opacity: 0` to match the `opacity: 1` on `:hover` so a transition is defined. These might not be the only issues though.

```
'&::after': {
  //  Try add this
  content: "''",
  //  Perhaps also add this so it creates a transition
  opacity: 0,
  minHeight: "100vh",
  marginTop: 0,
  marginBottom: -50,
  justifyContent: "center",
  background: "linear-gradient(360deg, #dfe566 30%, #7DF334 70%)",
  transition: "all 3s ease",
};
```